# Drop rows efficiently in Dask

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I'm trying to drop null values on a dask dataframe, the example in the documentaton works well for columns:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("test.csv",assume_missing=True)
df.dropna(how='all', subset=None, thresh=None).compute()
```

But if I try to specify axis 0 in order to filter by rows, I get this error:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("test.csv",assume_missing=True)
df.dropna(how='all', subset=None, thresh=None,axis=0).compute()
```

The documentaton also says:

```
axis:{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0 (Not supported in Dask)
```

So I wrote this as a walkaround:

```
df = dd.read_csv("test.csv",assume_missing=True)
filter_ = ~(df.isnull().all(axis=1).reset_index()[0])
df.loc[filter_].compute()
```

But it does not look pythonic.
Also, I'm resetting the index, and as far as I know that is an inefficient operation in dask.

Comment: You mentioned **I get this error**, but there is no error message in your question, please add full stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the axis parameter is not supported in Dask's [`dropna()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.dropna) as of version 2.2.0. To drop columns you'll have to 'manually' check if the colunm contains `Nan`s an drop it if so:

for `how = 'any'`:

```
df.drop([c for c in df.columns if df[c].isna().any().compute()], axis = 1)
```

for `how = 'all'`:

```
df.drop([c for c in df.columns if df[c].isna().all().compute()], axis = 1)
```

Although not explicitely listed in the examples, `isna()` is a [trivially parallelizable operation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html#scope) like `max()`, so it is efficient.